# store a json object in ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer

Want to store a json object in `ArrayBuffer`

```
function stringToUint(string) {
    var string = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(string))),
        charList = string.split(''),
        uintArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < charList.length; i++) {
        uintArray.push(charList[i].charCodeAt(0));
    }
    return new Uint8Array(uintArray);
}

function uintToString(uintArray) {
    var encodedString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, uintArray),
        decodedString = decodeURIComponent(escape(atob(encodedString)));
    return decodedString;
}
var str = {'x':'aaaa'},
    enc = stringToUint(str),
    dec = uintToString(enc);

console.log(dec.x);
```

`console.log(dec.x);` is printing `undefined. Am I doing it wrongly ?
here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DQJyX/137/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `stringToUint` expects a string, and passing an object to it will convert the `{'x':'aaaa'}` to `[Object object]` and returns an array representing that object object, and hence on calling `uintToString`, the array is converted back to `[Object object]`.

Simple solution is to use `JSON.stringify` to the object before passing it to function and then using `JSON.parse` to convert to original object.

```js
function stringToUint(string) {
    var string = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(string))),
        charList = string.split(''),
        uintArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < charList.length; i++) {
        uintArray.push(charList[i].charCodeAt(0));
    }
    return new Uint8Array(uintArray);
}

function uintToString(uintArray) {
    var encodedString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, uintArray),
        decodedString = decodeURIComponent(escape(atob(encodedString)));
    return decodedString;
}
var str = {'x':'aaaa'},
    enc = stringToUint(JSON.stringify(str)),
    dec = JSON.parse(uintToString(enc));
    
document.write(dec.x);
```

Comment: How can I get back JSON from what we get  from `Utils.stringToUint(JSON.stringify(str))`

Comment: using `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 2):

in order for it to work you need, in the `stringToUint` function call to `JSON.stringify`.

```
function stringToUint(string) {
    var string = btoa(unescape(JSON.stringify(string))),
        charList = string.split(''),
        uintArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < charList.length; i++) {
        uintArray.push(charList[i].charCodeAt(0));
    }
    return new Uint8Array(uintArray);
}

function uintToString(uintArray) {
    var encodedString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, uintArray),
        decodedString = decodeURIComponent(escape(atob(encodedString)));
    return decodedString;
}
var str = {'x':'aaaa'},
    enc = stringToUint(str),
    dec = uintToString(enc);

console.log(dec);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code for `stringToUint` is ~40% faster, [benchmark link](https://jsperf.com/string-to-uint-compare/1)

```
function stringToUint(string) {
  const str = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(string)))
  const uintArray = []
  const len = str.length

  let i = -1

  while (++i < len) {
    uintArray[i] = str.charCodeAt(i)
  }

  return new Uint8Array(uintArray);
}
```